# How can I generate hundreds of digits of pi in MATLAB with Ramanujan's converging series?

Tags: matlab, digits, pi

I am trying to use Ramanujan's converging series here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#20th_century

I am using digits() and vpa() to increase the precision of each of the terms, as seen in my code.

```
num_digits = 20000;
digits(num_digits+1)
ram_pi_init = vpa(0);
t1 = vpa(2);
t2 = vpa(sqrt(2));
t3 = vpa(1/9801);
for k=0:8
    t4 = vpa(factorial(4*k)); %INF after k=42
    if t4 == Inf
        t4=1;
        for kk = 1:4*k
            t4 = vpa(t4*kk);
        end
    end
    t5 = vpa(1103+26390*k);
    t6_temp = vpa(factorial(k));
    if t6_temp == Inf
        t6_temp=1;
        for kk = 1:k
            t6_temp = vpa(t6_temp*kk);
        end
    end
    t6 = vpa(1/t6_temp^4);
    %t7 = vpa(1/396^(4*k)); Does not work properly
    t7=vpa(1);
    for kk = 1:4*k
        t7 = vpa(t7/396);
    end
    increment = vpa(t1*t2*t3*t4*t5*t6*t7);
    ram_pi_init = vpa(ram_pi_init + increment);
end
ram_pi_sym = vpa(1/ram_pi_init);
ram_pi_str = char(ram_pi_sym);
ram_pi = [];
for i = 3:num_digits+1
    ram_pi(i-2) = str2num(ram_pi_str(i));
end

%% compare
correct_streak = 0;
for i = 1:num_digits
    if pi(i) == ram_pi(i)
        fprintf('Y\n')
        correct_streak = correct_streak + 1;
    else
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: What is your question? And is there a reason why you're not using the [Chudnovsky variant](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/clevescorner-computing-pi.html?s_v1=32283390_1-8KASKY) of this summation?

Answer (score 0):

Assume `k` to be large (250+). Take a closer look how you use `factorial`. `factorial(k)` is `inf`, and the vpa representation of inf is still inf: `vpa(factorial(k))`. Instead, you have to convert to VPA first, then use factorial: `factorial(vpa(k))`

The same with `vpa(1/396^(4*k))`, your result is inf and then you convert to vpa. `vpa(1/396)^(4*k)` should be fine.